DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated when running frontend server
I am encountering a DeprecationWarning related to the punycode module when running my frontend server.
The warning message is:
(node:6208) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.

This warning appears when I run my frontend server using the command npm run dev.
Here is the relevant portion of the output:
(frontend@0.1.0 dev) next dev
(node:6208) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.

I have ensured that all my dependencies are up to date. Despite this, I am still receiving the deprecation warning. The issue seems to be originating from the MongoDB Node.js driver and its dependencies.
Here is the dependency chain causing the issue:
└─┬ mongodb@6.4.0
  └─┬ mongodb-connection-string-url@3.0.0
    └─┬ whatwg-url@13.0.0
      └─┬ tr46@4.1.1
        └── punycode@2.3.1

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this warning and update my dependencies accordingly. Thank you in advance for your help.
backend package.json:
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start",
  "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "14.1.4",
   "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
   "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
   "yarn": "^1.22.22"
  },
   "devDependencies": {
 "@types/node": "^20",
   "@types/react": "^18",
  "@types/react-dom": "^18",
  "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
  "postcss": "^8",
  "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
  "typescript": "^5"
 }
  }
  `{
 "name": "backend",
 "version": "1.0.0",
     "description": "",
    "main": "server.js",
   "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "start": "node server.js",
   "dev": "nodemon server.js"
 },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
  "axios": "^1.6.7",
  "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
 "cors": "^2.8.5",
 "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
 "express": "^4.18.3",
 "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
   "mongodb": "^6.4.0",
 "mongoose": "^8.2.1",
   "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
  "validator": "^13.11.0"
 } 
}`

I have updated my Node.js version to the latest one, and I have also ensured that all dependencies in my project are up to date. Despite these updates, I am still encountering a DeprecationWarning related to the punycode module when running my frontend server.

You might talk to the vendor about that: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-5709

I had the same issue with a Nextjs project.
Try to downgrade your Node version to the latest LTS available. At the moment it's v20.12.2.
Hope it helps.

This really doesn't solve the issue, as I am already on Node 16
